# Why does maven install fail during javadoc generation?

Tags: maven-1

When running 'maven install', I get the following..

> [INFO] [javadoc:javadoc {execution:
>   default}] [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] BUILD ERROR [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] An error has occurred in
>   JavaDocs report generation:Exit code:
>   1 - java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.PackageUseWriter.generatePackageUse(PackageUseWriter.java:180)
>           at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.PackageUseWriter.generatePackageList(PackageUseWriter.java:124)
>           at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.PackageUseWriter.generatePackageUse(PackageUseWriter.java:110)
>           at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.PackageUseWriter.generatePackageUseFile(PackageUseWriter.java:99)
>           at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.PackageUseWriter.generate(PackageUseWriter.java:78)
>           at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.ClassUseWriter.generate(ClassUseWriter.java:116)
>           at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.generateOtherFiles(HtmlDoclet.java:92)
>           at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration(AbstractDoclet.java:122)
>           at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractDoclet.java:64)
>           at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:42)
>           at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:23)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:269)
>           at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:143)
>           at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:340)
>           at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:128)
>           at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:41)
>           at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:31)

Command line was: `/home/fsl/jdk1.6.0_12/jre/../bin/javadoc @options @packages @argfile`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post the relevant parts of your pom?

Answer (score 13):

Also, if you have:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9.1:jar (default-cli) on project coolproject-api: MavenReportException: Error while creating archive:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - javadoc: warning - No source files for package org.coolproject.api
[ERROR] javadoc: warning - No source files for package org.coolproject.api
[ERROR] javadoc: warning - No source files for package org.coolproject.api.listeners
[ERROR] javadoc: error - No public or protected classes found to document.
```

Java compiler understands sources directories with package-style names like:

```
coolproject-api/java/org.coolproject.api/
```

and there are no problems with it, but *maven-javadoc-plugin* doesn't. So try to change your "physical" packages layout to:

```
coolproject-api/java/org/coolproject/api/
```

Comment: You would also encounter the error in this answer if you had the correct directory structure for maven but had entries in the pom to declare an alternate <sourceDirectory>; most likely the declared sourceDirectory is empty as reported.  If running a release:perform, this error won't appear until the very end.

Answer (score 3):

To drop the -use option in maven-javadoc-plugin, use the following configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <use>false</use>
                <links>
                    <link>http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/</link>
                </links>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Sorry - this fix didn't work for me, using maven-javadoc-plugin 2.8.1

Comment: also didn't work for me, using maven-javadoc-plugin 2.9.1 (newest version as of now)

Answer (score 1):

There is an [unfixed bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5101868) that seems to be your problem. From the bug description the known workarounds are either to drop the -use option or use JDK 1.4.2. You're using Java 6 so this may be the case.

The line the NullPointerException is occuring at is:

```
printHyperLink("", pkg.name(), Util.getPackageName(pkg), true);
```

So perhaps the problem is occurring because of a typo in your package.html file?

Answer (score 1):

From that bug report, this will occur when one has classes in the default package and -use is on. So one solution is to move the classes in the default package into a named package.

Annoying that this bug hasn't been fixed in the javadoc tool distributed with some of the distributions, such as MacOS X Lion.

The bug appears to have been fixed in the openjdk 6, at least from inspection of the source code. Download of that source available at: http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/

Answer (score 0):

Look at your environment variables and delete the `CLASSPATH` variable or add your package path.

`javadoc` uses the classpath to determine the packages. If the path is not in your variable it will fail.